# Lifers and the Squad

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

Amanda Waller offers reduced prison time to criminals if, as part of Task Force X, they complete dangerous missions and return alive. But what if Waller wants someone who's been sentenced to life without parole? Does she have the authority to commute that sentence?

Comment: "*Complete the mission, you get time off your prison sentence."*. Presumably for someone who's got life without parole, they might get life *with parole*